# Multiplicative Analogue of Integration

Tags: integration

The name of this might be slightly deceiving compared to what I wish to know.

We know that to find the area under the curve, we partition the range in question, say $[a, b]$ into $n$ sub-ranges. We can then represent the area (with respect to this partition) as $${\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{n}f(t_{i})\,\Delta _{i},}$$ where $\Delta_i$ equals $x_i - x_{i - 1}.$

To find the true area, that is without any loss of accountability of the finitely divided ranges, we take the limit of this sum as $n$ approaches infinity; $${\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum _{i=1}^{n}f(t_{i})\,\Delta _{i}.}$$

My question is whether there is a well-defined analogue to this where the summation is replaced by a product, ie. perhaps something of the form $${\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod _{i=1}^{n}f(t_{i})\,\Delta _{i}.}$$ What I mean by well-defined is that for a finite range, the value of this "multiplicative" integral is also finite, provided that the function $f$ is smooth (doesn't have any discontinuities in the range $[a, b]$).

Comment: Yes this is a well studied field. See [Product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral).